# Sequence And Series question 19

Tags: sequences-and-series

19. If $S_{1},S_{2},S_{3},\cdots,S_{m}$ are the sums of $n$ terms of $m$ AP’s whose first terms are $1, 2, 3,\cdots$, and common differences are $1,3,5,\cdots$ respectively, then show that $S_{1}+S_{2}+S_{3}+\cdots+S_{m}=\dfrac{mn (mn+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $1st$ AP, $S_1 = \frac{n}{2} \{2*1 + ( n-1 ) 1 \}$

In $2nd$ AP, $S_2 = \frac{n}{2} \{2*2 + ( n-1) 3 \}$

In $3rd$AP, $S_3 = \frac{n}{2} \{2*3 + ( n-1 ) 5 \}$

--- and so on

In $m^{th}$ AP, $S_m=\frac{n}{2} \{2*m + (n-1)*(2m-1 )\}$

$S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + ... + S_m=\frac{n}{2} \{ 2*(1+2+3+...+m) + (n+1)*(1+3+5+...+[2m-1])\}$

$=\frac{n}{2} \{ 2* \frac{m}{2} (1+m) + (n-1) \frac{m}{2} ( 1+2m-1) \}$

$=\frac{n}{2} \{ m+m^2 + (n-1) m^2 \}$

$=\frac{n}{2} \{ m+m^2 + nm^2 - m^2 \}$

$=\frac{1}{2} nm \{nm+1\}$

Comment: Please explain me what have you done in the 4th step from below , I was not able to understand that equation, it would be a great help if you could explain me that